# SharePoint 2010 Export Search Results of Document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, export

We get the correct results from our Search in SP2010 but want to export just those files. How do we do this in a non manual way? Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Powershell to move the files to a new library. Then use Export-SPWeb to only export that library.

[Export sites, lists, or document libraries in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/export-a-site-list-or-document-library)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script to export (site collection scope) search results to csv file and download the files from search results:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "http://sp2010"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\results.csv"
 
#Get the site collection
$Site = Get-SPSite $SiteURL
 
#Frame Query to search: Get all documents sorted by Last modified
$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($Site)
$SearchQuery = "site:$SiteURL ContentType:document NOT FileExtension:aspx"
$keywordQuery.QueryText = $SearchQuery
$keywordQuery.SortList.Add("LastModifiedTime","Asc")
 
#Execute Search
$SearchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor
$searchResults = $SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)
 
#Get Search Results
$Table = $SearchResults.Table
$Table | select Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime
 
#Export Search results to Excel
$Table | Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host -f Green "Search Results Exported to CSV File!"

#Get file URLs from Search results
$CSVSource = Import-CSV -path $CSVFile

#Download files from the CSV file
foreach ($Row in $CSVSource) {
    $SiteName = Get-SPWeb ($Row.SiteName)
    $File = $SiteName.getFile($Row.Path)
    Write-host $File.Name 
    $FileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream(("C:\Users\<User>\Documents\Download\"+$File.Name), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $Writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($FileStream)
    $Writer.Write($File.OpenBinary())
    $Writer.Close()
}
Write-Host -f Green "Download Completed!"
```

Remember to change the parameters as well as the folder path for downloading in the script.

Reference: [PowerShell to Search SharePoint and Export Results to CSV using Keyword Query.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/powershell-to-search-sharepoint-export-results-using-keyword-query.html)